# How to access iPhone's front, back and two bottom built-in microphones?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation, microphone

I am working on a Swift 4 app that records amplitude and sample data using AudioKit. My goal is to record the noise, and I need to skip Apple's automatic noise-cancelling. As you know, iPhone has 4 built-in microphones.

1. I want record only using front microphone. How do I do this using AudioKit or AVFoundation (in Swift not Obj-C)?
2. Checking AVFoundation docs, apple provides three options front, back, and bottom:

   [, , ]

I guess the bottom refers to noise-cancelled result of two bottom microphones (one in left side of lightning port, one on right side). My question is that how do I separate them and access data individually? I want to reverse noise cancelling addition of the two bottom microphones to detect noise.

3. How do I record with all built-in microphones *at the same time* an log amplitude data in an array? I want my data array to have 8 columns: seperate recording data for each microphone, 4 microphones x 2 stereo channels/microphone = 8 columns.

**Any hint is appreciated.**

Comment: I'm on the AudioKit core team and I just wanted to point out that although AudioKit is tagged here, there's nothing particularly AudioKit-y about the problem. It is a general question about access particular microphones on the iPhone which AudioKit does not address.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to access more than 1 microphone at a time, but have a look at `AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement` which is "Appropriate for applications that wish to minimize the effect of system-supplied signal
processing for input and/or output audio signals."